# how to check if a meeting has ended in bigbluebutton without continuous polling from client?

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am trying to integrate bigbluebutton in my web application. I came across a scenario where I have to notify the client which is in angular that the meeting has ended and perform certain tasks after that. I tried but was not able to find anything. Continuous polling is an option but still wanted to know if there is another way. Not able to find anything as of now . Any sugestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the product manager for BigBlueButton.  You can now register a callback in BigBlueButton (which you pass as a parameter on the `create` API call) to have it call your application whenever a given meeting ends.  See

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#end-meeting-callback-url

Comment: Just curious what all webhooks are available right now? like for userLeft, userJoin etc? Any list (already checked api doc)